# Open InternetExplorer COM object to do some automation using Wating from WPF app, but keep UI responsive. is this possible?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, com

I have an app that runs a process which needs to open an internet explorer, go to an url, and do some stuff there, input some data, and return. 
This usually takes a while (several pages that need to be filled, doesn't matter). The problem is, while this process is being done, the calling app (a standard wpf app) UI is unresponsive/frozen. When the process returns, i have some info that i need to set in one of the WPF app's objects
The main problem is that since IE needs to be called from within an STA thread, if I try to call it from within the dispatcher asynchronously or synchronously, for some reason the UI is blocked (i have tried with different DispatcherPriority-es but didn't get lucky).
If i start a new BackgroundWorker, that thread is in MTA mode (and i can't switch it back), so there's a problem and i have an exception
I'm really lost here, could anyone put some light into this? maybe what i want to do is simply not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating your own background thread (not relying on BackgroundWorker), and set its ApartmentState to STA?

Comment: i've tried this, and i got a "Failed to set the specified COM apartment state." InvalidOperationException on the Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); call

Comment: ok, i managed to solve it using this approach. 

Thread workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { doMyStuff(); }));
         workerThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
         workerThread.Start();